# how to add org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils to maven in intellij?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, intellij-idea, import

I should add `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;` to intellij 10. 
how can i add it to maven and use it in the code.I need to be able to use `FilenameUtils` in my code.
i have already this : `org.apache.commons` in maven.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you are asking for how to specify the dependency on Commons-IO in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: this one exsist in my pom.
      `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-parent</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: whats wrong in my project? why `apache` is red colored in `import org.apache. ...` see [this](https://imgur.com/a/fbHSf)

Comment: Any reason why `groupId` is `artifactId` instead of `org.apache.commons` or so?!

Answer (score 11):

You need to add commons-io to your dependencies.

[Here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io) you can find snippets and choose version you need.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the above dependency in your pom.xml and update the maven project. The maven will download the required jar from the maven central repository.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```